# ...but no matter "how"

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

> A: Was she the one who left?
>
> B: Yeah, but it wasn't exactly a happy marriage.
>
> A: Okay. But no matter **how**, I guess a divorce is always difficult.
>
> B: Sure.

Does it make sense to use "how" instead of "what" in this context? Is it natural?

Answer (score 1):

> No matter **what** [...]

and

> No matter **why** [...]

are stock phrases that mean "in any case" and "regardless of cause" respectively. They really add little meaning to a sentence.

> No matter **how** [...]

is also a stock phrase normally meaning "without regard to manner or means."

> No matter **how**, we need to get to New York by tomorrow.

That sentence is fine because (presumably) there are many ways to get to New York by tomorrow, by car, by bus, by train, by plane, by ferry.

Divorce, however, is a legal proceeding. It does not have numerous modes of accomplishment. So

> No matter **how**, a divorce is always difficult.

sounds very odd and is unclear.

However, ***how*** can also be used to indicate degree, but then we need to know degree of what. So the following sentence is normal and clear

> No matter how amicable, a divorce is always difficult.

In short, "no matter how" sounds odd in the specific context of your example although it is a standard stock phrase in other contexts.